# Do I need a helper column, or can I do this with a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am using this formula

```
=IF((LEFT($B26,2)="<p"),0,IF($B26="",0,IF($F26<>"",0,(FIND("""../",$B26)))))
```

To parse data similar to the following.

```
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;contractor information</nobr><br> 
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../City_Electrical_Inspectors.htm"><b> City Electrical Inspectors</b></a><br>
<nobr>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="../City_Electrical_Inspectors.htm"><b>inspection</b></a></nobr><br>
```

My problem comes in cases such as the first line, in which the line is not a new paragraph nor a link, and my `FIND` returns an error of `#VALUE!`

Id like to create an `IF` test to scan the line for the existence of the pattern in my `FIND` statement before processing that statement. I figured that looking for an error condition may be the way to go. However, the only way I can envision this is as a self-referential formula, similart to the following pseudocode.

IF(ISERROR($L26)=TRUE,$L26=0,L$26=the-result-of-the-formula-above)

Can this be done with a formula or do I need to use a new helper column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Excel 2007 or newer, you can wrap the `FIND()` function in an `IFERROR()` function.

```
=IF((LEFT($B26,2)="<p"),0,IF($B26="",0,IF($F26<>"",0,IFERROR(FIND("""../",$B26),0))))
```

For older versions of Excel that do not support `IFERROR()`, you can use the following longer solution.

```
=IF((LEFT($B26,2)="<p"),0,IF($B26="",0,IF($F26<>"",0,IF(ISERROR(FIND("""../",$B26)),0,FIND("""../",$B26))))
```